# How to preserve layers structure/groups when exporting GeoPDF from QGIS

Tags: layers, grouping, geopdf

I have a project with lines, polygons, points, GeoTIFFs and map services that are all organized in groups. QGIS can create a layered GeoPDF from them beautifully, but the resulted PDF won't preserve the grouping!  All layers will be at one top level without grouping.

Is there anyway to fix this?